# Polyhedron intersection with plane that maximizes number of vertices of intersection polygon

Tags: geometry

Given convex polyhedron with N vertices, what is the largest number of vertices that can have a polygon which is intersection of polyhedron with some plane? My lower bound formula is M = 2*N - 4

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.